# default model field attribute in Django

Tags: python, django, models

I have a Django model:

```
    @staticmethod
    def getdefault():
        print "getdefault called"
        return cPickle.dumps(set())

    _applies_to = models.TextField(db_index=True, default=getdefault)
```

For some reason, `getdefault()` is never called, even as I construct instances of this model and save them to the database. This seems to contradict the Django [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default):

> Field.default
>
> The default value for
>   the field. This can be a value or a
>   callable object. If callable it will
>   be called every time a new object is
>   created.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Update**:

Originally, I had this, but then I switched to the above version to debug:

```
_applies_to = models.TextField(db_index=True, default=cPickle.dumps(set()))
```

I'm not sure why that wouldn't work.

**Update 2**: I'm still having difficulty with this. Here is my model:

```
class Threshold(models.Model):
    # ...
    _applies_to = models.TextField(db_index=True, default=lambda: cPickle.dumps(set()))
```

And a test:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.threshold = Threshold() 

    self.threshold.save()

def test_default_applies_to(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.threshold._applies_to, cPickle.dumps(set()))
```

This test fails. I'm not sure why.

```
FAIL: test_default_applies_to (apps.threshold.tests.ThresholdTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 27, in test_default_applies_to
    self.assertEqual(self.threshold._applies_to, cPickle.dumps(set()))
AssertionError: 'N.' != 'c__builtin__\nset\np1\n((ltRp2\n.'
```

Why might this be happening? Perhaps I don't understand how `default` is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the staticmethod decorator and it will work :

```
def getdefault():
    print "getdefault called"
    return cPickle.dumps(set())

_applies_to = models.TextField(db_index=True, default=getdefault)
```

**Edit** : From your Update i think the easiest way in this case is to simply do:

```
models.TextField(db_index=True, default=lambda: cPickle.dumps(set())
```

And for why your first example wasn't working , it's because `cPickle.dumps(set())` si not a callable you are evaluating `cPickle.dumps(set())` when the model is defined.

Hope it can help :)

Comment: @Rosarch : you have to put the name of your model , i named __MyModel__ just as an example :)

Comment: @Rosarch: i just edited my answer sorry for that , now i have tested and it work , hope it can help :)

Comment: @Rosarch: i have just run the tests just like you did and i didn't get any error !!! i can't tell why you do get an error there but i can tell you that in my case the test doesn't fail so you have to check something else , well hope you find the answer :)